# Check if object coordinates meets requirements

Tags: java

I am making game, where I need to check if object`s coordinates meets requirements (Destination coordinates) with permitted +- difference.

Example:

```
int x; //current object X coordinate
int y; //current object Y coordinate

int destinationX = 50; //example X destination  value
int destinationY = 0;  //example Y destination value
int permittedDiference = 5;

boolean xCorrect = false;
boolean yCorrect = false;
```

I am trying to create algorithm, checking

```
 if (x == destinationX + permittedDifference || x == destinationX - permittedDifference)
 {
     xCorrect = true;
 }

 if (y == destinationY + permittedDifference || y == destinationY - permittedDifference)
 {
     yCorrect = true;
 }
```

It sounds like most simply way, but maybe there is better one? Will be grateful for some tips.

Comment: Other than perhaps refactoring into `xAllowed` or `xBetween` etc. methods, what else could you do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [`Math.abs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29) method here. Get the absolute difference between `x` and `destinationX`, and check whether it's less than or equal to `permittedDifference`:

```
xCorrect = Math.abs(x - destinationX) <= permittedDifference;
yCorrect = Math.abs(y - destinationY) <= permittedDifference;
```

Comment: It works well, I am just wondering, what do you think, which aproach would be better to use, faster I mean, this one using abs method, or first one you posted at beginning? I will be checking those "requirements" all the time, on every update, for few objects, of course this does not require lot of calculations, but still I would like to know your opinion, thank you.

Comment: @Matim. Well, I didn't posted any other solution. And as far as speed is concerned, you should really not bother about that. Readability is the major concern here. And it becomes quite clear when using this approach, that what you are trying to do, rather than normal `if-else` block. Also, if you are frequently doing these tests, then it would be better to move these logics in some methods, and give that a meaningful name, and invoke it. That would be far more clearer.